# bring more than one languages into a common compiler

Tags: java, compiler-construction, programming-languages

For my assignment , I want to know about common compiler  list? I really didn't understand this...Please anybody give an idea about this..I Google it but didn't get proper solution

Thanks

Comment: Kind of a vague and overly general question. I'm not sure it's answerable as asked. What exactly don't you understand? What do you understand? Are you asking a volunteer to re-write a tutorial for you? That's surely not going to happen.

Comment: please i am student.I really don't know these question that why i asked this question. This is my assignment question. Please may i know that why did you put downvote?

Comment: Do some reading on the GNU compiler suite.  This is a family of compilers for different languages that (at least to some degree) share a common code generator back-end.

Comment: @Kartheepan - as a student, you also need to *learn* to ask more intelligible and focussed questions.  That's what the downvotes etc are telling you.

Comment: @Kartheepan you have do more search on Google . i gave +1 for new to this site & student

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you asking about common compilers? Or you want one compiler that can handle multiple languages? Try [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/). It can compile:

- C
- C++
- Objective-C
- Fortran
- Java
- Ada
- Go

Comment: Thanks this information.I give some helpful to me.. I want to know the common compiler.

Comment: He just answered that!!  It is called GCC.  Now read the link in the answer.  If that doesn't help, then restate your question more clearly.

Comment: *"helpful to me"* Please consider up-voting it then.

Comment: Nope. The link is clicked, and off the OP goes, never to return.